# Which file is the source codes of regtest net located?

Tags: source-code

I try to compare the source codes between main net and regtest net of bitcoin. I am not sure where the source codes of regtest located. Would someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Because regtest is supposed to be test network, it has to be pretty similar to mainnet. Thus there really isn't separate code for regtest only, most of the code is shared between the two networks. The differences are really only defined by a few parameter changes which can be found in [chainparams.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L281).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. What I really want to know is the miner part for Regtest. I believe what original Satoshi Nakamoto told. So, how to reduce the system cost, specially the mining cost is the biggest issue. I think the two basic functions of mining can be separated into two parts;  one for find the data recorder, another for system safety. I think the getwork is better than getblocktemplate for unti-concentrated, maybe only internal miner is ever better.

Comment: There's no mining in regtest. Regtest was also made half a decade after Satoshi left.